# Why is SELinux preventing opendkim from accessing private key files, and how do I fix it?

Tags: postfix, opendkim

I'm trying to set up opendkim with Postfix (on CentOS).

Having copied my known good private key into place, I'm seeing this:

```
Nov 16 12:54:26 [host.domain] setroubleshoot[10093]: SELinux is preventing opendkim from open access on the file /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 8de37e21-88ab-46af-9927-e6040f6bfc97
Nov 16 12:54:26 [host.domain] platform-python[10093]: SELinux is preventing opendkim from open access on the file /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private.

       *****  Plugin restorecon (99.5 confidence) suggests   ************************

       If you want to fix the label.
       /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private default label should be etc_t.
       Then you can run restorecon. The access attempt may have been stopped due to insufficient permissions to access a parent directory in which case try to change the following command accordingly.
       Do
       # /sbin/restorecon -v /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private

       *****  Plugin catchall (1.49 confidence) suggests   **************************

       If you believe that opendkim should be allowed open access on the mykey.private file by default.
       Then you should report this as a bug.
       You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
       Do
       allow this access for now by executing:
       # ausearch -c 'opendkim' --raw | audit2allow -M my-opendkim
       # semodule -X 300 -i my-opendkim.pp
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was because I *moved* (`mv`) my private key file into place, via a user home directory, and it came with the wrong SELinux extended permissions.

---

EDIT: See comment from @MichaelHampton, it may be sufficient to delete the file and then *copy* (`cp`) it into place, instead of (`mv`).

---

EDIT: Or see comment from @HermannB, once you have the problem to fix it, it may be sufficient to simply run `/sbin/restorecon -v /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private`.

---

My original answer:

To fix recreate the key file from new in its directory, for instance:

```
$ cd
$ sudo mv /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private .
$ su
> cd /etc/opendkim
> cat /home/[a.user]/mykey.private > mykey.private
> chown opendkim mykey.private
> chgrp opendkim mykey.private
> chmod 600 mykey.private
```

It is creating the file from new (i.e. the line with `cat`) which fixes the basic problem. If you create it from new in the `keys` directory, it gets the correct SELinux permissions automatically and opendkim can read it. The last three lines give the file the restricted permissions which opendkim also requries.

Comment: Once you correctly identified the problem as an SELinux issue, following the suggested approach would have been just as easy I recon `/sbin/restorecon -v /etc/opendkim/keys/mykey.private`

Comment: Yes, I misread(?) that. It _says_ the 'default label should be etc_t. Then you can run restorecon' - which sounds as if you have to fix the label first, then run 'restorecon'. From what you're saying, running `restorecon` does fix the label, in which case yes, that is easier!

Comment: You didn't copy the file, you moved it. If you had copied it, it would have been fine. You could also have used `mv -Z`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Would that work even if there was no file in place to copy over?

Comment: What do you mean "no file"? If there's no file, you can't move or copy it!

Comment: Sorry, no pre-existing destination file to overwrite is what I meant!